# Openstack + Chef + Jenkins for continuous delivery

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, openstack, continuous-delivery

I am brand new with Openstack and Chef tools.
I am trying to setup a Continuous Delivering Process where I imagine something like following:

From Jenkins create a Pipeline where we have Jobs:

- **Job1**: compiles, runs unit test + static analysis and deploys RPM build/artifacts into Artifactory.
- **Job2**: Download RPM files from Artifactory and save them all together into a Yum Repository.
- **Job3**: Clean and Recreate in Openstack the Lab infrastructure (Routers, Private Networks, Nodes with a clean image). After that, clean and re-register those Nodes in the Chef-Server specifying the run-list cookbooks that each node will have.
- **Job4**: Runs Functional and Integration Test using infrastructure created in Job3. Publish results.

The doubt I have is how to implement Job3, the ways I see to implement this is using in Jenkins configuration Openstack command lines as nova and neutron, and for Chef also using knife and chef-client command, but for all that I shall have access to OpenStack controller server and all Chef Nodes.
Is there a more tidy way to implement this without just using command lines, something like Jenkins Plugins, Chef recipes or some other way? 
What I don't like of adding in Jenkins configuration is that is not under version control, I would like something like chef recipes that perform all Openstack and Chef infrastructure setup and have those recipes under version control. But I am not sure how to implement all this with recipes and how then they will be applied from Jenkins.
It is correct the idea I have or there is other ways to implement this approach?

Thank you for the help.

Comment: not familiar with any openstack jenkins plugins.  i think command line may be the only way.

Answer (score 0):

For provisioning and orchestrating application infrastructure, I would recommend using [Heat](https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Heat). A single YAML file describes your desired application environment.

The openstack documents describe how nova servers can be [configured using chef at boot time](http://docs.openstack.org/user-guide/content/user-data.html#d6e2498) using a cloud-init.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using CloudMunch which integrates into Openstack to deliver continuous delivery and deployments.

Disclaimer: I work at CloudMunch.